# How to convert tchar pointer to char pointer

Tags: mfc, visual-c++

I want to conver a tchar* to char * is this  possible . if yes how to do it. I use unicode setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find wcstombs works great for doing this sort of thing,

Answer (score 2):

A `TCHAR` is either a plain `char` or a `wchar_t` depending on your project's settings. If it's the latter, you would need to use [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450989.aspx) with appropriate code page parameter.

Comment: This information was missing in the original post, added after the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert the pointer, you need to allocate a new string that is "char" instead of "wchar_t"

the most elegant way to do this is with the ATL conversion macros because it will hide all the allocation and called to the functions mentioned in the other comments

example

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlconv.h>

void YourFunction() 
{ 
    TCHAR wszHelloTchar = _T("Hello!\n");

    USES_CONVERSION;   // a macro required once before using T2A() and other ATL macros

    // printf require a char*
    // T2A converts (if necessary) the TCHAR string to char
    printf( T2A( wszHelloTchar ) );
}
```