# TCHAR* to char* Conversion in c++

Tags: c++, conventions, type-conversion

I am trying to convert an TCHAR* variable to a char* variable. I am doing this because it is a must, and also because I am curious as to how this conversion would be done. I would really appreciate if you could help me. I am an c++ beginner.

Thanks .

Comment: I assume you are using Win32 APIs. Is that correct?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: [maybe this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721731/how-to-convert-tchar-pointer-to-char-pointer) or
[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613217/how-do-i-convert-from-tchar-to-char-when-using-c-variable-length-args)

Answer (score 1):

A [TCHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842072.aspx) is defined depending on your project settings. If your project is using multi-byte, it is already a char. If it's unicode, you would use [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert. You can do `#ifdef UNICODE` to check if your project is multi-byte or unicode. i.e:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
// TCHAR is unicode, convert to char
WideCharToMultiByte(...)
#else
// TCHAR is already char, do nothing
#endif
```

Comment: Which, of course, leads to unreadable code.  This is a good example of why using `TCHAR` is such a bad idea.  You need different code to handle `wchar_t` and `char`.  Just changing the type isn't sufficient.